# Not able to save foreign key serializer value

Tags: django

I have two models namely Media and Source.

Source is a foreign key field in Media table.

Below code shows the Serializer needed by REST API and to save the Media information.

What problem I am facing is that whenever I tried to POST data on `MEDIA` rest end point, `Source` value is not getting stored. It shows null.

```
{"id":44,"category":["deepfake"],"source":null,"status":"under_review","nsfw":false,"severity":"unknown","title":"Lakshmi Menon Deepfake(Bollywood Sexy Tease)","description":null,"type":"video","url":"https://adultdeepfakes.com/v1940539","file":"https://adultdeepfakes.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/B_LAKSHMI_MENON_AS_MAID_FUCKING_TRAILER_PAID_REQ_o_c_optimized.mp4","image":null,"data":{"views":"213","likes":"1","dislikes":"0","tags":""},"published_at":"2020-08-20T09:00:39Z","created_at":"2020-08-21T00:37:06.654294Z","updated_at":"2020-08-21T00:37:06.654305Z","persons":[]}
```

What I tried is remove `source = SourceSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)` code and save. It works!! But then in rest api it doesn’t show the source details.

Can anyone please advise me how I could get best of both the worlds?

```
class MediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the Media model
    """
    category = CustomSlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        many=True,
        read_only=False,
        slug_field="name",
    )

    source = SourceSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Media

        fields = "__all__"

        read_only_fields = [
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
        ]
```

Comment: you want to select an existing source record or you want to create and set source record?

Comment: @PruthviBarot I want to select an existing source record and assign to the newly created media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have declared source as `read_only`, it will not be considered in `POST` it will show only in 'GET' request.

so try this way:

```
class MediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    source_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='source',queryset=Source.objects.all(),write_only=True)
    source = SourceSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Media

        fields = "__all__"

        read_only_fields = [
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
        ]
```

then do post request as:

```
{
  "id":44,
  "category":["deepfake"],
  "source_id":2, # select existing id of source
...
}
```

and `source` will show a nested object in `GET` request